# replace an empty value with null using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl

i have some empty values in my table named partner(city,...) and when i want to change them to null values using replace(city,'',null) it returns all the values of city as null not only those who was empty

Answer (score 2):

You could use the CASE statement.

```
SELECT
CITY = CASE WHEN city ='' then NULL else city end 
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, just another way to get there, SQL Server offers a "shorthand" version of the `CASE` expression for situations like this; the [`NULLIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function.

```
SELECT
  NULLIF(city,'') AS CITY
FROM TABLE
```

If the first argument for `NULLIF` matches the second argument, the function returns `NULL`. So here, if your `city` column is an empty string, the function will return `NULL` for you.

Note that `NULLIF` is also available in SSIS expressions, if you prefer to do your data transformations there.

Answer (score -1):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(city, '') as city
```